# load netflix zuul routes values from database

Tags: java, spring, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, api-gateway

I was learning about api gateway technology `netflix zuul`. I figured out all things in place and was able to route my apis with `zuul` proxy url. Below is my code:

**Main class**

```
package com.example.springbootzuulgatwayproxy;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import com.example.springbootzuulgatwayproxy.filters.ErrorFilter;
import com.example.springbootzuulgatwayproxy.filters.PostFilter;
import com.example.springbootzuulgatwayproxy.filters.PreFilter;
import com.example.springbootzuulgatwayproxy.filters.RouteFilter;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
public class SpringBootZuulgatwayproxyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootZuulgatwayproxyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public PreFilter preFilter() {
        return new PreFilter();
    }
    @Bean
    public PostFilter postFilter() {
        return new PostFilter();
    }
    @Bean
    public ErrorFilter errorFilter() {
        return new ErrorFilter();
    }
    @Bean
    public RouteFilter routeFilter() {
        return new RouteFilter();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-zuulgatwayproxy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-boot-zuulgatwayproxy</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>






        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId> 
            </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
zuul.routes.employee.url=http://localhost:8090
zuul.routes.employee2.url=http://localhost:8090
server.port=8080
```

and then there are 4 filter classes (Pre,Route,Post and Error) all extending `ZuulFilter` class.

everything is working fine. but now the requirement is that, all `zuul.routes.[entity].url` fields in `application.properties` file have to be loaded from database, along with their `url` values. How can I achieve this requirement. Please advice. I have tried pre-populating/updating application.properties file with similar keys. Was able to update/write application.properties file, but actual effects does not happen at runtime. What should I do in order to set those route keys defined in properties file to get dynamically loaded from mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

Updating routes in `application.properties` doesn't automatically trigger `ZuulProperties` bean to be reloaded. Regardless of where routes are stored you would need a bean similar to:

`@Primary
  @Bean(name = "zuulConfigProperties")
  @RefreshScope
  @ConfigurationProperties("zuul")
  public ZuulProperties zuulProperties() {
    ...
  }`

UPDATE to include routes configuration:

```
zuul:
  ignoredServices: "*"
  routes:
    zuulDemo1:
      path: /zuul2/**
      serviceId: demo-zuul-api1
# stripPrefix set to true if context path is set to /
      stripPrefix: true
```

This is covered in a blog post I wrote, [Routing requests and dynamically refreshing routes using Spring Cloud Zuul Server](http://tech.asimio.net/2017/10/10/Routing-requests-and-dynamically-refreshing-routes-using-Spring-Cloud-Zuul-Server.html#adding-support-to-dynamically-update-the-zuul-routes), although it doesn't store routes in a DB but in a `Bitbucket`-backed file that has a WebHook that sends a POST request to the `Zuul` server which then publishes a message to a broker (`RabbitMQ`) for subscribers to get the changeset.

Comment: sorry I am not able to understand your architecture here, you are using third party configuration `@ConfigurationProperties("zuul")` with the method `zuulProperties()`. But I wanted to know, how can I load those properties (similar to `application.properties` mentioned in question above), in this special method returning `ZuulProperties`.

Comment: is there something I can do with the `Route Filter`? you can also explain me using a `Map` instead of `db`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store routes value in database you can check this blog.

https://programmer.group/spring-cloud-gateway-service-zuul-three-dynamic-routing.html

**Database structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `sys_zuul_route` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'router Id',
  `path` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Routing path',
  `service_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Service name',
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'url agent',
  `strip_prefix` char(1) DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Forward without prefix',
  `retryable` char(1) DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Do you want to retry?',
  `enabled` char(1) DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Is it enabled?',
  `sensitiveHeaders_list` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Sensitive request header',
  `create_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Creation time',
  `update_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Update time',
  `del_flag` char(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Remove identity (0-normal,1-Delete)',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC COMMENT='Dynamic routing configuration table'
```